# audiofile throwing error on file size even though settings changed

Tags: files

> An unrecoverable error occurred. The uploaded file likely exceeded the maximum file size (2 MB) that this server supports.

Every time try to upload 8mb mp3 I get the above error even though have changed settings in field edit from 2 MB to 20 MB and using unmanaged VPS with plenty of space and memory plus php.ini file increased.

Comment: Did you try changing (increasing values) `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` in your `php.ini` file? If you've tried that, did you restart the Apache server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have apache access control, you can try to add the `php.ini` settings into

```
ini_set('post_max_size','16M');
```

and

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize','16M');
```